# Why does the jQuery load() method with multiple sprites (i.e., a bool)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite

I'm working on a program that needs to load two sprite images. I'm now using a different implementation, but I first had:

```
$(sprite1 && sprite2).load(function() {
    // code to run on load
});
```

I realize that I was actually calling load() on a bool, which in theory doesn't seem to me like it should it should work - but it did, or at least seemed to.

Any thoughts on why using load() this way works?

Comment: are you able to call ajax functions ? i think it will not initate ajax requests

Answer (score 1):

According to docs.  [Jquery Load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> If no element is matched by the selector — in this case, if the
>   document does not contain an element with id="result" — the Ajax
>   request will not be sent.

1. So Your load method will not call an ajax request.
2. .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[**`.load()`**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)</kbd>

**Description:** Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.